# What's the default classpath when not specifying classpath?

Tags: java

Wondering what will be the default classpath when not specifying classpath option?

Comment: $JRE_HOME and the current working directory, as far as I recall.

Comment: Create a class that just prints out System.getProperty("java.class.path") and you'll know :-)

Comment: @StijnGeukens, Don't forget that we need to run that code form the command line, otherwise the IDE will modify the `-classpath` flag.

Comment: @Pacerier: indeed, valid point.

Comment: Please note that "_the CLASSPATH variable is one way to tell applications, including the JDK tools, where to look for **user classes**. (Classes that are part of the JRE, JDK platform, and extensions should be defined through other means, such as the bootstrap class path or the extensions directory.)_". That is, the majority of classes loaded at runtime is **not** specified in the classpath.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The current working directory (`.`).

From [The Java™ tutorials: PATH and CLASSPATH](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html):

> *The **default value of the class path is "."**, meaning that only the current directory is searched. Specifying either the CLASSPATH variable or the -cp command line switch overrides this value.*

### Does this include subdirectories?

No, no entry in the classpath is "recursive". You have to list each subdirectory (or jar) explicitly. However, if you have an `Example.class` file representing class `pkg.subpkg.Example`, and the default classpath is used, then this file should live in `./pkg/subpkg/Example.class`.

If `java` attempts to resolve `pkg.subpkg.Example` it will look in `/pkg/subpkg` of each classpath entry. I.e. you do not have to list `.`, `pkg`, and `pkg/subpkg` in the classpath, only `.`.

Comment: What does this even mean? Current directory for what? Where the java.exe file is? Where the source is? Very confused....

Comment: The current working directory is the directory you last `cd`'ed into. If your Windows shell says `C:\dir\subdir>` then the current working directory is `C:\dir\subdir` (or on *nix, if your prompt says something like `user@machine:/usr/bin$` then the current working directory is `/usr/bin`).

Answer (score 26):

I think people are answering this person's question too literally. Yes, CLASSPATH defaults to ".", but there are a bunch of classes that automatically get loaded even when you don't set CLASSPATH or use the -classpath command line argument.

The following is a good place to learn about this process:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/findingclasses.html

Comment: the CLASSPATH the question refers to is that used by the classloder loading user and third party components.                                                      Other two classloaders exist:                                                                        - external library classloader                                                                                - java standard libraries classloader.                                                                        These classloaders know by themself where to look for classes.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for.  Thank you very much for the link.  I was very confused about how the JRE libraries got loaded, since their location wasn't on the class path.

Answer (score 9):

It is the current Working directory "."

You can check it out your self too

```
class CheckClassPath{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.class.path"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The default class path is the current directory. Setting the CLASSPATH variable or using the -classpath command-line option overrides that default, so if you want to include the current directory in the search path, you must include "." in the new settings.
[official manual](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html)