# Java default ClassPath environment variable

Tags: java, classpath, default

I accidentally changed my Classpath environment variable in Windows system properties and am now getting a heap of errors on execution, what is the default? What should I be pointing it towards?

Many thanks in advance!!

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8227682/whats-the-default-classpath-when-not-specifying-classpath

Comment: If you're having problem about Java path variable check this out: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html

Comment: Default classpath is ".", as http://stackoverflow.com/a/8227712/1083704 says

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ClassPath` environment variable is only used when you want your computer to look at a specific location for your `.class` files; generally speaking, it doesn't exist unless you make it exist, whether on purpose or a side effect of some installer.

Most of the time, the applications you are running (primarily JRE), know exactly where to look for `.class` files. Most of the time.

However, if you were refering to the `PATH` environmental variable, that can be more of an issue.

Oracle has a throughout step-by-step on setting your enviromental variables (I can vouch, I just had to reset my `PATH` this morning): http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html

However, here are the steps as I remember them:

1. **Start Menu**, right click **Computer**, Choose **Properties**
2. **Advanced System** on the far left, and there is an **Enviromental Variables** button near the bottom, click it
3. In the bottom context menu, find the `PATH` variable and choose edit
4. Put a semicolon after the last one, and then add "*C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib*;" and "*C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin*;" or wherever your java "lib" and "bin" folders are

And then you should be all swell and dandy, no harm no fowl.

Answer (score 2):

The difault of `CLASSPATH` environment variable is nothing, i.e. by default this variable does not exist. If you had something defined you should know what did you define. If you do not know, try to analyze your stack trace and understand what is needed to your application to work.

If you have problems, send your stack trace here and we will try to help you.