# Using java.exe with .class file from Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, command-line

I have a programming working in Eclipse.  I need to be able to send the project to my instructor, who will run it from the command line with java.exe.

The program takes arguments, and I have tested those within Eclipse and they work fine, however, when I attempt to use java.exe to execute the main.class file that is in the bin folder of my project I get the following error:
Error: Could not find or load main class C:\Workspace\Sort\bin\Main.class

I have JRE 1.8.0_60 installed on my system and not the JDK.  However, whatever Eclipse uses to compile, I should be able to use as well.  I know I can export it as a JAR, but that is not part of the assignment and I don't think JAR files take arguments.

Any ideas?

Comment: jar file can take arguments. How do you try to call the class File ? You shoult edit your question and give us the commandline

Comment: First you  will need to check if your jar has bundled all the class files in bin folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind that the [default classpath for `java.exe` only includes the current working directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8227682/639520). So if you're not executing `java` from the `bin/` folder of your project, it won't know where to find your class. You need to either run from `C:\Workspace\Sort\bin` or use the `-cp` option to include that folder on the classpath. For example:

```
java -cp C:\Workspace\Sort\bin Main arg1
```

Also note that you *should not* include the `.class` file extension when specifying the name of the class.

Comment: Thank you.  That was my problem.  I added `.class` to my compiled code, and it did not run.  Once I removed that, it worked great.

Answer (score 0):

You can send parameters when executing a jar :

1. using arguments

cmd: `java -jar Myapp.jar arg1 arg2`

code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  //args[0] = arg1
  //args[1] = arg2
}
```

2. using parameters:

cmd: `java -Darg1_name=arg1 -Darg2_name=arg2 -jar Myapp.jar`

code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  //System.getProperty("arg1_name") = arg1
  //System.getProperty("arg2_name") = arg2
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I want to write it as:
cmd: `java.exe Main.class arg1`