# Why do I have to specify Java classpath for my .class file when I am at the same folder in windows CMD?

Tags: java, windows, command-line

I have a simple "test.java" in a folder. I am under that folder that contains and "test.java" already ran "`javac test.java`". A "test.class" file is created.

But when I try to run "`javac test`", my environment always returns

> Error: Could not find or load main class test

unless I type `java -cp . test` to get java executing the test.class file.

Why?

Thanks.

Comment: Because the current directory is not included in the classpath by default.

Comment: @kayaman, yes but current directory should be included as default on Windows, I just found out that my env var CLASSPATH is set to something different.

Comment: @GhostCat, accepted. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You answered your question itself.

When you do

```
java test
```

Then the current directory is not in your classpath.

Thus it works when you go with `-cp .` (as that says: add "." aka the "current directory to the current classpath)

On the other hand, by default "." should be in the default classpath ( see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8227682/whats-the-default-classpath-when-not-specifying-classpath) ).

So, two explanations:

- As said, some subtle hickup around your file names
- Your environment actually sets a classpath ENV variable; and that one excludes "."

Comment: I agree with this answer -- if you're going to use it, be aware that the command line option option includes a period: `-cp .`; the period represents the current directory.

Comment: Thanks for the input; I updated my answer regarding that aspect; so maybe your agreement could manifest itself as upvote then ;-)

Comment: Thank you GhostCat. The second explanation is the reason - my dev environment var on Windows is somehow set as "CLASSPATH=(some/folder)", causing Java to look that folder up instead of current working directory. Now I removed it and "java test" worked.

Comment: Noted. Thank you @arcy.