# Java classpath issues on arch linux

Tags: java, archlinux

For me to get any java program to run, I have to perform the following steps:

```
javac program.java
java -cp .  program
```

The output of `echo $CLASSPATH` is `=/usr/share/java/`
I was wondering why I have to manually specify the classpath everytime and how I can work around this issue.
I am using archlinux with openjdk8. I encountered the same issue with openjdk9 as well.
Any help on the topic is appreciated.

Comment: I think this answers your question nicely. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8227682/whats-the-default-classpath-when-not-specifying-classpath

Comment: @killjoy Yeah it tells me that the classpath is supposed to default to "." which is the current working directory which is not happening in my case. Any ideas as to how I can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set `$CLASSPATH` to `/usr/share/java`, so java will not look in the current directory anymore.
To fix this, you can run `unset CLASSPATH` for temporarily unsetting the environment variable.

Depending on wheter or not you need `$CLASSPATH` pointing to `/usr/share/java`, you can either remove the offending line (something like `export CLASSPATH=/usr/share/java`) or add the line `export CLASSPATH=.:$CLASSPATH` at the end of the file, wherever you set your environment variables (e.g. `~/.bashrc`, `~/.zshenv`, ...).

Cf. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/environment_variables

Comment: Yes, thank you.  
Adding '.' to my CLASSPATH seems to have solved this issue.