# Can't import classes from jar

Tags: java, spring, maven, import, jar

I am having problems importing classes from a JAR library into my project. Please see the screenshot.

I have tried several things both in Eclipse and IntelliJ, both adding directly and adding through Maven. None of this helps, I still get a red underline.

In IntelliJ I tried:

1. Project Structure - Modules - Dependencies - Add jar.
2. Tried creating a lib folder, add it as a library and place the jar inside and then setup as dependency.
3. Adding through maven pom.xml with direct path to the jar.

In Eclipse I tried:

1. Java Build Path and adding it to my build path.
2. Maven - Update Project.

Here is my pom.xml to get the local jar.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>uk.co.pervasive_intelligence.simulator</groupId>
  <artifactId>protocol</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <scope>system</scope>
  <systemPath>C:\Users\Vas-DELL\Desktop\simulator-1.2.2.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

Strangely, I am able to see the jar and the classes inside the jar (screenshot). But still can not import them. Let me know please if there is anything else I can provide.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: From your image I can infer that either you're refering to the classes using the wrong package declaration... or the Jar file is wrongly packaged. You cannot import classes from the BOOT-INF folder within a Jar file... 
Could you show the JAR structure? (you can open the jar using any zip or rar tool)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a lib/ dir in the root of your project folder. Put your Jar there. Add this to your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>uk.co.pervasive_intelligence.simulator</groupId>
  <artifactId>protocol</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <scope>system</scope>
  <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/simulator-1.2.2.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

Do not use \ as path separator (even though you're using windows)

Run `mvn clean package` from the command line

You could also try installing the dependecy manually in your local repo:

`mvn install:install-file -Dfile=simulator-1.2.2.jar -DgroupId=uk.co.pervasive_intelligence.simulator -DartifactId=protocol -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar`

Then add this to your pom:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>uk.co.pervasive_intelligence.simulator</groupId>
  <artifactId>protocol</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

**EDIT:**

The jar file does not have the structure of a standard java library. In order to use that jar as a library, the packages of your classes should exist as folders in the base (or root directory) of your jar file. For example:

```
/META-INF
    /MANIFEST.MF
/uk
    /co
        /pervasive_intelligence
            /simulator
                /BaseComponent.class
                /SimulatorApplication.class
                /SimulatorException.class
....
```

Being a library jar file then the contents of the MANIFEST.MF can be as simple as

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for the steps - still same problem unfortunately. mvn package breaks with many "package does not exist".

Comment: From your image I can infer that either you're refering to the classes using the wrong package declaration... or the Jar file is wrongly packaged. You cannot import classes from the BOOT-INF folder within a Jar file...

Comment: Could you show the JAR structure? (you can open the jar using any zip or rar tool)

Comment: Here is the doc with the jar structure: https://expirebox.com/download/93787331d9fe9db39d50ebc5eabdc2f5.html

Comment: How can we use the classes from the jar file then if the classes cannot be imported?

Comment: Hi. What do you mean by "classes cannot be imported" ?

Answer (score 1):

Class files in **co.uk...** package is inside **BOOT-INF/classes** packed inside **simulator** jar, and cannot be accessed directly because it not part of jar's default classpath (".").

To understand better about jar classpath please check [What's the default classpath when not specifying classpath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8227682/whats-the-default-classpath-when-not-specifying-classpath)

**simulator** jar need to be packaged with classpath entry to add BOOT-INF/classes/...  in classpath to allow access to classes under BOOT-INF/classes.

For example to allow access to classes from package **uk.co.pervasive_intelligence.simulator.Component** with maven this can be done as

```
    <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <archive>

            <manifestEntries>
                <Class-Path>BOOT-NF/classes/uk/co/pervasive_intelligence/simulator/Component</Class-Path>
            </manifestEntries>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

If You Use SpringBoot and InteliJ Idea， when you have excute mvn clean package command, you should use packagename.jar.original in maven pom for The jar file  have the structure of a standard java library.

```
/META-INF
    /MANIFEST.MF
/uk
    /co
        /pervasive_intelligence
            /simulator
                /BaseComponent.class
                /SimulatorApplication.class
                /SimulatorException.class
....
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced with a similar issue and analyzing the inner jar structure of other working libraries I have noticed that my custom library that I'm trying to import had the incorrect structure descripted by [@Martin Zaragoza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6901184/mart%C3%ADn-zaragoza) in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51823581/4685215):

> The jar file does not have the structure of a standard java library.
> In order to use that jar as a library, the packages of your classes
> should exist as folders in the base (or root directory) of your jar
> file.

To fix the issue I have replaced the `build` pom section of my custom library imported with the following:

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```