# Where to store the downloaded .jar files?

Tags: java, jar, javac

As I am new to Java, I want to ask that where should I put the downloaded .jar files, so that I don't have to use `-cp` option in `javac` command to compile it?

For example, suppose I have written a java code "HelloWorld.java" to do a basic input output and I have done `import java.io.*;` or `import java.util.*;`, and doing `javac HelloWorld.java` compile command on it works fine, however, if I have some (for example) `import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;` line in my code and it won't compile without me downloading the `mongo-java-driver-3.10.2.jar` and putting it's location in `-cp` option of `javac`. (Like: `javac -cp "/home/shivam/Downloads/*" HelloWorld.java`).

So I just want to ask that where should I store the  `mongo-java-driver-3.10.2.jar` file in my computer so that, using just the `javac NameOfCode.java` command without the `-cp` option will compile my code successfully?

FYI, I have Ubuntu 18.04.2 and am using Java-11.

Thank you!!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8227682/whats-the-default-classpath-when-not-specifying-classpath might help

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam
Thanks, but it is saying that the default classpath is ```.``` or the current directory. But it is temporary, i.e., I want a fixed place where I can store all the .jar files so that I can run a program from anywhere without ```-cp``` option. (Just like python, I want to just import the thing and not worry from where will it be imported.)

Comment: Using a build tool such as [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/) or [Gradle](https://gradle.org/) can greatly simplify pulling in dependencies (including transitive dependencies) as well as compiling, running, and packaging your project.

Comment: @Slaw
Thanks. I am aware of Maven and Gradle. But I just want to do it with ```javac```.

Comment: I believe you can set the `CLASSPATH` environment variable. Note that will apply to all invocations of Java on the computer (though explicitly specifying `-cp` might override it, not sure). If that doesn't help then unfortunately I don't know another option (I rarely use the command line directly), but you might find something in the [tool documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/tools/javac.html#GUID-AEEC9F07-CB49-4E96-8BC7-BCC2C7F725C9).

Comment: @Slaw
What I really want to find is where all the bootstrap .jar files (containing java.util.*) are stored, and why not store my .jar there instead of explicitly setting the ```CLASSPATH```. Thanks.

Comment: In Java 9+ the JDK modules are, I believe, contained in a file named `<JDK_HOME>/lib/modules`. This is also where your modules (when using modules) end up after using `jlink` to create your own image.

Comment: @Slaw
Thanks for the info. And as ```<JDK_HOME>/lib/modules``` is a file, that means there is no way I can store the jar somewhere for it to work (again, without using the classpath thing). Sad.

Answer (score -1):

You can put them in JAVA_HOME/lib, where JAVA_HOME is the path to your jdk setup

Comment: I tried already, doesn't work. Probably because I have Java-11 and after java-9 perhaps, they removed the jre from the java installation. And the rt.jar file was also in JAVA_HOME/jar/lib/ which is no more in Java-11. So putting my jar also doesn't work.