# custom yaml configuration files in a config folder outside the project (Spring)

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a project with some config files. I need to externalize them to allow the user to edit them. It's a spring boot application and my files are in a yaml format.

It's not application.yaml, it's some custom files with different names.

I use bean annotations. For example, one of my beans looks like this :

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties
@PropertySource(value="globalConfiguration.yaml", factory = YamlPropertySourceFactory.class)
public class GlobalConfiguration {
//some fields
//accessors
}
```

When the file is in src/main/resources, it works well but once built it reads the file inside the jar  (which is normal)
What I would like to do is to read in priority the yaml file from a config folder which is near the lib folder like this :

```
 - bin
 - config
       globalConfiguration.yaml
 - lib
       myApp.jar
```

I tried using the parameter --spring.config.location="classpath:./config/" (and /./config and ././config and /config and config...) but nothing work I have this error :

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Config data location 'classpath:/./config/' does not exist

Action:

Check that the value 'classpath:./config/' is correct, or prefix it with 'optional:'
```

EDIT :
Now I tried to add my config files to the classpath like this :

```
set CLASSPATH=%APP_HOME%\config\*;%APP_HOME%\lib\myJar.jar;someDepencies.jar
"%JAVA_EXE%" %DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS% %JAVA_OPTS% %MYAPP_OPTS%  -classpath "%CLASSPATH%" my.Main.Class %*
```

It's the bat generated by gradle when I build the project so I just added %APP_HOME%\config\*; to the classpath variable.
But it didn't change anything.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8227682/whats-the-default-classpath-when-not-specifying-classpath

Default classpath in java is set to your current working directory. If you start your myApp.jar from it's directory the config folder will not be present in the classPath and therefore cannot be found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it had nothing to do with the classpath. the spring.config.location works perfectly well but the directory used is the current one when launching the bat and my app was on a windows shared folder so I wasn't able to do a cd \mysharedfolder.. .

To make it works, there was two option :

- To move the app in a local folder. Then move to the folder of the app and so the relative path works from there.
- The second option is to set the complete path of the config folder like this :

```
    --spring.config.location="\\\\mysharedfolder\\someSubDirectories\\config\\"
```