# Java Classpath not using current directory

Tags: java, classpath

Yes... Again question about classpath. I compiled class file using command `javac Main.java`, then i tried to execute it by `java Main` And what do you think? I got that famous error: `Error: Could not find or load main class Main`. Why? I set the classpath env var to ".;" (without " of course). Whats wrong? Im using jdk 1.8.0_51.
In IDE (im using intellij idea 2021.3) everything is ok.
The only imported class is java.io.File.
It only works if i run it using command `java -cp <path to dir not including package folders> <full qualified class name>`
Windows 8.1

Comment: is your class inside a package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relying on the `CLASSPATH` system variable is a bad idea. One machine can be used to run many varied apps, so the concept of a 'global setting' is silly.

Try `java -cp . Main`.

### If that DOES work

Then you've been messing with your `CLASSPATH` environment var and removed `.` from it. Put it back. Or better yet forget about CLASSPATH; always use `-cp`; use `-cp .` if you like. Or make `jar` files and run them with `java -jar thejar.jar`, which ignores both `CLASSPATH` and the `-cp` parameter (instead that will look at the `Class-Path` entry in the jar manifest).

### If that does not work

Then you were not in the appropriate directory. Or, you're confused about packages. Let's say your `Main.java` looks like this:

```
package com.foo;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello");
  }
}
```

And you compile it; a `Main.class` file shows up.

`java` **cannot** run this unless `Main.class` is in a directory named `foo`, and that directory is in turn in a directory named `com`. Then, you put *the directory that contains `com`* on the classpath. **Not** the directory that contains `Main.class`. And then you run `java -cp theDirThatContainsCom com.foo.Main`. It is not possible to run this file with `java -(does not matter what you try it cannot be done) Main` - because you provide the full name of the class you want to run to `java`, and the full name is `com.foo.Main`.

Comment: Thank you! I have just made a simple program to rename many files fast and did not want to make a jar. Ok, now it works!

Answer (score 0):

Current directory (`.`) is a default classpath. But it does not include subdirectories automatically. So if you have packages, the directories should be added to classpath explicitly.

See a bit more info here [What's the default classpath when not specifying classpath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8227682/whats-the-default-classpath-when-not-specifying-classpath)